# First dropdown works, second doesnt bootstrap 3

Tags: css

In bootstrap I want to have 2 dropdowns, Only the first one in the code works. Even if I copy and paste

```
    <div class="dropdown" style="position: absolute; left: 30%">
    <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Games

        <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
        <li><a href="comingsoon/index.html">Coming Soon!</h5></li>
    </ul>
</div>
    <div class="dropdown" style="position: absolute; left: 60%">
    <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Games

        <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
        <li><a href="comingsoon/index.html">Coming Soon!</h5></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

(If i click the first one it opens the menu, if I click the second one it does nothing. These both are the same exact ones and do not work together)

Comment: Is this live somewhere we can test? Can you put together a fiddle? There's not enough css in here to tell what's going on.

Comment: [Docs say](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#dropdowns) that `.dropdown` should have `position: relative;`.

Comment: And while it's probably not causing the issue, you have a random `</h5>` in the "Coming Soon!" list item instead of the closing `</a>`.

Comment: @BSMP that might be the issue, the unclosed `<a>` will continue to wrap the entire document after that

Comment: @SergChernata There is no css in the code. Bootstrap does that for you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is that you have unclosed anchor tags. In two places you have `</h5>` in place of `</a>`. If you resolve that problem it works correctly.

```
<div class="dropdown" style="position: absolute; left: 30%">
    <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Games

        <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
        <li><a href="comingsoon/index.html">Coming Soon!</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

## [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/ogtXOIp5Wp)

Comment: Thanks! I will mark this as answer when it allows me to!